# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying trying to get a better understanding of configurations in Spring. I am have read some examples and tutorials, but so far, the stuff that is happening is still somewhat mysterious, for example:

**blah.properties:**

```
blah.url=127.0.0.1:2181
```

**Blah.java**

```
package com.blah.test;

[...]

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.blah.test")
public class BlahApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlahApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**BlahConfig.java**

```
package com.blah.test;

[...]

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:blah.properties")
public class BlahConfig {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BlahConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    configurer(
        Environment environment, 
        @Value("${blah.url}") String url
    ) {
        String s = environment.resolvePlaceholders("${blah.url}");
        log.info("blah url: "+s+" / "+url);
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Without anything, this will (in part) do everything nicely, so without anything set, the environment will resolve the to "127.0.0.1:2181", and i can override this from an environment variable and/or a system property.

So far so good. But I was expecting the `@Value` annotation to pick up the same thing. It doesn't - why not?

Also ... I am assuming that static methods in `@Configuration` classes are among the first things to be instantiated, and apparently even more so if they extend `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. It seems there is a huge potential for confusion in figuring out exactly in what order stuff gets initialized. Does anyone have an idea in which parts I would have to turn up the logging in order to get a better idea when and why things are ordered?

thanks!

Comment: The `@Value` is processed before the `@PropertySource` also your construct is dubious at least. Also when using Spring Boot why don't you use the default `application.properties` and mess around with additional files yourself. Leverage the tools you use instead of hacking around them.

Comment: i had a first go, and it did not behave exactly as expected. so i suspected a misunderstanding and tried to mess with it, mostly to understand what is happening there. but also, i am not entirely sure if application.properties is always the right way to go? specifically ... i am looking into using something like zookeeper for looking up configuration.

Comment: also, why would @Value be processed BEFORE @PropertySource? is there any reason?

Comment: The `@Bean` is a factory method, which is processed very early as well as the `@Value` annotation at that point. When invoking the method the `Environment` is injected/used but that at that point has already bean modified with the loaded `@PropertySource`.